# SSIS parameter crashes Visual Studio

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, visual-studio-2015

I am experiencing a weird behavior with SSIS parameters.

At the start of the SSIS package, I have a script task. In the Script Task Editor I select a package parameter as a read only variable.

When I execute the package, Visual Studio crashes.

Other Details:

- Visual Studio 2015
- Target Server Version is SQL Server 2012
- Execute Script by itself will work
- SQL Server Data Tools - 14.0.60923.0
- Two data flows and an email task after the Script Task
- Disable data flows and it works without crashing VS

Is there a problem using package parameters in this manner?

It crashes shortly after I right click and select Execute Package. No break points set.

Comment: Verified you're on the latest and greatest version of both Visual Studio as well as the SSDT plugin? Is there something intrinsically "weird" about the parameter and what you are doing with it in the script task? The unified SSIS hosting environment (ability to target 2016/2014/2012) is new in this release so quite possible you've hit a bug. if you change target to 2016, does it still repro? Curious on your SSDT version. I'm at 14.0.60918.0 but I don't show any available updates.

Comment: @billinkc They updated to version 60923 about a day or two after 60918.

Comment: The parameter is a date. Beyond that nothing weird. Have not extensively tested different target versions, but I initially it looks to clear up by setting to 2014 or 2016.

Comment: I am now experiencing this behavior in other tasks. Tried to use Execute SQL task and had a similar experience. I would make a change, execute package and crash. Restart VS and package runs. Rinse and repeat. Move the package to the server and it executes. But development has become a PITA.